# Groovy Json parse with filter

Tags: json, parsing, groovy

I'm beginner with groovy. Could you please help with parse all value by pattern from json?

```json
String json = '''{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
  "builds" : [
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "#1500",
      "number" : 1500
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "Name1-develop-(#1499)",
      "number" : 1499
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "Name2-develop-FullPackage-(#1498)",
      "number" : 1498
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "Name2-develop-FullPackage-(#1497)",
      "number" : 1497
    }
  ]
}'''
```

So I need to get result with filter like `Name2-develop-FullPackage*` and exclude all other value. Ideally write these values into an array.

I tried code below, but I got blank [] result

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def obj = jsonSlurper.parseText(json)
def result = findAll{ obj.builds.displayName == "Name2-develop-FullPackage" }
println(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it almost right:

```
String json = '''{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
  "builds" : [
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "#1500",
      "number" : 1500
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "Name1-develop-(#1499)",
      "number" : 1499
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "Name2-develop-FullPackage-(#1498)",
      "number" : 1498
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "displayName" : "Name2-develop-FullPackage-(#1497)",
      "number" : 1497
    }
  ]
}'''

def obj = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText json
def result = obj.builds.findResults{ 
  it.displayName.startsWith( 'Name2-develop-FullPackage' ) ? [ displayName:it.displayName, number:it.number ] : null 
}

assert result.size() == 2
assert result.toString() == '[[displayName:Name2-develop-FullPackage-(#1498), number:1498], [displayName:Name2-develop-FullPackage-(#1497), number:1497]]'
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you know how to exclude ```_class:hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild``` string from the output?

Comment: maybe I do :). see the edit